# cordova background geolocation support without app getting terminated after a while

Tags: android, ios, cordova, geolocation, background-process

I'm searching for a way to implement background geolocation support on iOS without that the app getting terminated by OS and stopping the tracking of the device. In my application I'm using these two plugins to get geolocation support in the background:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

and 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

But after the app is a while in the background the app gets terminated by iOS and isn't sending any tracking points.

I already found this plugin for our purpose:

https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt

But this plugin even tracks the geolocation even if the app gets terminated by the user manually, so I think there might be a hack or something like that so it wouldn't pass the iOS testing phase.

So how do I achieve this without any hacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the creator of Cordova-background-geolocation

There's no hack involved here and the plugin is 100% compatible with Apple guidelines.  The plugin's ability to keep tracking on app terminate / device reboot is granted simply because *iOS itself* persists listeners on geofences.  The plugin subscribes to a geofence around the last known position while in stationary mode.  When the app is terminated, the plugin, in its last dying breath, simply ensured a geofence exists around the last known position.

In addition, the plugin also subscribes to the iOS Background Fetch API, another API which iOS persists in spite of app terminate / device reboot.

No magic here.

Comment: If user close app tracking will still continue is this true?If yes can we remove background enabled text and icon?I want to track user coordinate every x second when user close app ..User should not see any background enabled info text

Comment: It's best to post support requests directly at the repo's issues.